# How to use service of translators in android app?

Tags: android, translators

I'm making an Android app. One of its feature is translating from Arabic to English or from English to Arabic. What are the free translators that allow us to use their service to do something like this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on the number of requests you'll be making.

Microsoft Cognitive Services has an API for this purpose and will allow you to make a small number of requests per month before you start having to pay, but after that they charge a fee depending on the number of requests you make.

This seems pretty typical of the available vendors - Watson has a similar plan available (250,000 characters free as of 10/26/2016, then you have to pay after that - currently $0.02 for each 1000 characters beyond that).

You can also look into [Google Translate for Android](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2).